# Any way to programmatically add an app to Samsung Unmonitored apps list?

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, battery

Samsung Android 7.0 has the warning notifications for putting my App to sleep. This will even kill the sticky service. Is there any way to add my app to the "Unmonitored Apps". Or use intent to bring the user to this setting page at least.

Comment: did u get any solution for this?

Comment: @NabeelThobani Not yet, I will post it here whenever I have.

Comment: I tried sending out high priority push notification to my app and onPushReceived i started a service again. This seems to be working for few attempts but i will test it thoroughly because i still have doubts on this solution

Comment: This might be a workaround. But Samsung Galaxy S8 plus has a feature called "Always sleeping apps"(Select apps that will be put to sleep immediately when they aren't bing used.) If user put your app in this list, I think your app will be killed by the system very soon even your backend service triggered by the push notification time from time.

Comment: I saw "Always sleeping apps" option in s7 and s8 both.